# Different errors on a switch case

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have so many errors on my switch.  At first it said all the errors were expected a declaration.  I have another function with the same layout that works fine.  And another one that still has around 4 errors that say expected a declaration.  I'm just really confused as to why.

```
void staff_menu_second_step() { //error here says it wants me to change it to ;
    //requires staff to login in order to do anything
    if (staff_login == true) {
        while (error == 0) {
            cout << "Press 1 to add book\n";
            cout << "Press 2 to check user info\n";
            cout << "Press 3 to check customer info\n";
            cout << "Press 4 to search for a book\n";
            cout << "Press x to exit\n";
            cin >> action_choice;

                switch (action_choice) {
                    case 1:
                        add_book();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        staff_info();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        customer_info();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        search_book();
                        break; //error here (says its not in a switch case)
                    case 'x': //error here (says its not in a switch case)
                        cout << "You pressed x\n";
                        break; //error here (says its not in a switch case)
                    default:
                        break; //error here (says its not in a switch case)

                if (action_choice != 1 || action_choice != 2 || action_choice != 3 || action_choice != 4 || action_choice != 'x') {
                    error = 1;
                    cout << invalid_input;
                } else {
                    error = 0;
                    break; //error here (says no loop or switch statement -- but i'm using it to end the while loop
                }
            }
        } //error here (expected declaration)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Do you really want `if (action_choice != 1 || action_choice != 2 || action_choice != 3 || action_choice != 4 || action_choice != 'x')` to be inside the block for the `switch`?

Comment: `//error here (says its not in a switch case)` I don't believe your code is the same that you are showing then. That error seems to indicate that you have a misplaced `}`

Comment: @NathanOliver: not to mention that condition will always be true.

Comment: Not sure what type `action_choice` is, but the case labels appear to be using inconsistent types. My guess is it's a `char`, and you should be using `case '1':`, `case '2':`, etc.

Comment: No I want the if condition to be after the block switch.  However, when I tried ending the block switch with a } it said it wasn't supposed to be there.  And yes that is the correct error that it shows.  Hence why I'm very confused.  If it was a misplaced } I would probably be easily able to take it out or figure out where the other one is supposed to be.  And the function is called in a different function.  It's the second part of my staff login.  The first function changes the staff_login and error variables depending on the users entries.

Comment: My action_choice variable is a char.  Thank you for pointing out my missed ''.  I didn't catch that.

Comment: It for sure looks like you are missing a } after your default case. Basically we do not believe that this code produces the error you say though. It has many errrors but  not ones that would produce that message

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a little scary. First, you didn't show your entire class. Where is action_choice defined? I presume it's a char.

```
            switch (action_choice) {
                case 1:
                    add_book();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    staff_info();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    customer_info();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    search_book();
                    break; //error here (says its not in a switch case)
                case 'x': //error here (says its not in a switch case)
                    cout << "You pressed x\n";
                    break; //error here (says its not in a switch case)
                default:
                    break; //error here (says its not in a switch case)
            }
```

Note: I don't think your switch statement has a closing `}`. I had to add one. You have a bunch of if-statements after the default: break. So you might want to check that.

Okay, so if action_choice is a char, then your first 4 case statements need to check against chars.

```
  case '1':
```

et cetera.  1 and '1' are NOT the same value. If action_choice is a number, then it can't really be a char (like 'x').

From the amount of code you've given us, this is the best I can fix.